# Django. Как сделать фильтрацию по параметрам, если они могут быть пустые?

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, django-rest-framework, django-filter

Мой проект подключен к базе данных с городами, улицами, и магазинами. Моя задача обработать следующий запрос:

> (GET-запрос) `/shop/?street=&city=&open=` — получение списка магазинов;
>   Метод принимает параметры для фильтрации. Параметры не обязательны.                                 В случае отсутствия параметров выводятся все магазины, если хоть один параметр есть , то по нему выполняется фильтрация.

Мой код:

```py
def Shops(request) -> HttpResponse:
    street = request.GET.get("street", -1)
    city = request.GET.get("city", -1)
    open = request.GET.get("open", -1)
    if open == "1":
        shops = Shop.objects.filter(shop_city_id=city, shop_street_id=street,
                                    shop_time_to_open__lte=timezone.now(),
                                    shop_time_to_close__gte=timezone.now())
    elif open == "0":
        shops = Shop.objects.filter(shop_city_id=city, shop_street_id=street,
                                    shop_time_to_open__gt=timezone.now(),
                                    shop_time_to_close__gt=timezone.now())
    return render(request, "getshops.html", {"shops": shops}, status=200)
```

Укажите пожалуйста, каким образом я могу решить свою задачу?

Comment: Не рекомендую использовать слово `open` в качестве идентификатора. В python есть соответствующая [функция открытия файлов](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=open#open). Использование в качестве идентификаторов названия встроенных функций и/или зарезервированных слов чревато множеством непредвиденных ошибок

Comment: Здравствуйте cauf. Спасибо за совет. Больше так называть переменную не буду. Не знаете как решить мою проблему?

Answer (score 0):

Я уже давно не пишу на Django, но сделал бы что-то вроде этого *(далее по тексту может быть не корректный код в применении к Django; расценивайте его скорее как псевдокод для передачи смысла идеи)*:

```py
def Shops(request) -> HttpResponse:
    street = request.GET.get("street", -1)
    city = request.GET.get("city", -1)
    open_par = request.GET.get("open", -1)

    if city != -1:
        query = Shop.objects.filter(shop_city_id=street)
    else:
        query = Shop.objects.all()

    if street != -1:
        query = query.filter(shop_street_id=street)

    if open_par != -1:
        if open == "1":
            shops = query.filter(shop_time_to_open__lte=timezone.now(),
                shop_time_to_close__gte=timezone.now())
        elif open == "0":
            shops = query.filter(shop_time_to_open__gt=timezone.now(),
                shop_time_to_close__gt=timezone.now())
    else:
        shops = query.all()

    return render(request, "getshops.html", {"shops": shops}, status=200)
```